# Start Service Bus Client from BackgroundService

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a `ServiceBusClient` class that creates a `QueueClient` which is used to listen for messages on a bus. I have looked at the following articles to set this up:

[Background tasks (Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)

[Hosted services (Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

[Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

My `ServiceBusClient` class that handles the `QueueClient` looks like this:

```
public class ServiceBusClient : IServiceBusClient
{
    public ServiceBusClient(IEventService eventService, ServiceBusClientOptions options)
    {
        ...
        queueClient = new QueueClient(options.ConnectionString, options.QueueName);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        RegisterOnMessageHandler();
    }

    private void RegisterOnMessageHandler()
    {
        ...
        queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
    }

    private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var eventMessage = EventMessage.FromMessage(message);

        await eventService.Write(eventMessage);

        if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
        }
    }

    private Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        // log errors
        ...

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }  
}
```

I was hoping to launch from an `IHostedService` or even by extending the `BackgroundService`. In the examples I find, work is constantly being executed in a while loop which does not fit my scenario since I am only trying to run a single command.

So I created a super simple implementation like this:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    serviceBusClient.Run();

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // empty loop to keep running for lifetime of pod       
    }
}
```

If removing the `async` I obviously need to return something. I tried `Task.CompletedTask` but that required me to change the return type to `Task<Task>`.

If I have the `async` in place, I will need to `await` something, but I am not sure what.

This does not feel right. I would assume I would need to change something in  the `ServiceBusClient`, but I am unsure what, since the `ProcessMessagesAsync` is async and does the heavy lifting in the background from my understanding.

All I want is for my web app to start listening for messages until it dies. How can I do that?

Comment: What version of .Net Core are you using? I've run a similar scenario (Service Bus listener via IHostedService ) and used the Task return type => return Task.CompletedTask; with no issues on .Net Core 2.1. As it was for a presentation the code isn't particularly elegant, but it's here if it will help: https://github.com/serri588/streamanalyticsdemo/blob/master/WebApplication1/Listeners/LogEventListener.cs I ignored the Cancellation Token in the start method, but that shouldn't matter for this issue.

Comment: On 2.2. I implemented a `IHostedService` in the end where I could launch the client from the `Start` method. But then we had to refactor to a console app anyway so that is done now :P. Using the console app also made it easier to create a more testable ServiceBusClient and message handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gave up on using `BackgroundService` and implemented `IHostedService` instead.

```
    public class MessageListenerService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IServiceBusClient client;
        private readonly ITelemetryClient applicationInsights;

        public MessageListenerService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            client = serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceBusClient>();
            applicationInsights = serviceProvider.GetService<ITelemetryClient>();
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            applicationInsights.TrackTrace(new TraceTelemetry("MessageListenerService is starting"));

            client.Run();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            applicationInsights.TrackTrace(new TraceTelemetry("MessageListenerService is stopping"));
            return client.Stop();
        }
    }
```

If you find issues with this code please let me know in the comments and I'll update as appropriate.

In the end we created a console app for it anyway.